# find number in array using stack in Assembly 8086

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, x86-16

i have an assignment to write program in Assembly lang that accepts 3 parameters to the stack and search n value in the array.

here is the full Explain the assignment:

> Write a procedure must be written that accepts three parameters on the
>   stack: a word array address, the number of objects in the array, and a
>   number (we will denote it here in n). The procedure will look for n in
>   the array and return in the ax register the address of the first
>   element in the array whose value is equal to n. Ax register. If value
>   is not in array, return -1. In the data segment, two word sets of
>   different lengths must be defined with different values. You must
>   write a main procedure that runs the find procedure for each of the
>   two configured arrays, with two different search values. The search
>   values ​​will appear in another setting in the data segment. The main
>   procedure prints the address where the value is located, or a note if
>   it is not found. Reminder: Sets a word layout of 4: arr1 dw 300, 50,
>   15, 48

i need help with how to start the code? how to send the parameters to the stack?
Thanks in advance for helpers

edit this is my code for now:

```
.STACK  64
.DATA 
arr db 9 dup ?
arr1      dw  1,2,3,4,5   
arr1size  dw  5         
newline db  0AH,0DH,'$' ; newline 
arr2        dw  4,5,6,7,10,10 
arr2size    dw  6        
resu      dw  ?  ; result var
errmsg  db  "of - voer flow"
n dw  0

sendToStack proc
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    sub sp, 24
    lea dx, arr1
    push dx



    pop dx
    pop bp
    end proc
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    call sendToStack

end
```

suggestions for continue?

Comment: *"how to send the parameters to the stack?* `PUSH`

Comment: can you please give me an example for how i should do it?

Comment: No, you have to do your own homework. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. You should have learned about the instructions required to do this assignment *before* getting the assignment. Perhaps go back and review your textbook/lecture notes/Google. This site works better after you have already written some code. Then you can ask *specific* questions, and we can help you to refine it.

Comment: Do a Google search on "8086 stack frame" or "8086 pass parameters on stack" and you'll find lots of examples and explanations to get you started.

Comment: While googling may/should help, there are many variants how to create and run 8086 code, your lectures may have particular specific target platform/variant in mind, so you should start first with the course material, to be sure you are searching for correct examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I developed on Linux for 32-bit `x86` architecture which finds a number inside an array. The code might help you get started, but is **NOT using** `stack`, therefore the stack version remains a homework for you. I tested the code with `gdb` debugger to step through the instructions and check the register values, as far as I checked, the code works as expected.

We have the following `makefile`, so on linux terminal just type `make` and the assembly code inside `asmtut.s` file is compiled and linked:

```
asmtut: asmtut.o
        ld -o asmtut asmtut.o
asmtut.o: asmtut.s
        nasm -f elf -o asmtut.o asmtut.s
clean:
        rm *.o asmtut
```

The assembly code inside `asmtut.s` is:

```
section .data

array dw 18,99,22,72,40,55,110,23       ; array to be searched

length dd 8     ; array length; note array length can be 32-bit

number dw 40    ; number we search for, i.e. wanted number
;number dw 88   ; this number will NOT be found: to check the not_found fork of the program

index dd 0      ; index of found number ; will be -1 if not found; note index is 32-bit

section .text

global _start
_start:

    xor edi, edi ; set edi=0x00 ; stores current array element index; use 0-based indexing
    xor ax, ax ; set ax=0x00 ; stores current array element
    xor ebx, ebx        ; ebx is used as an intermediary to store 32-bit index

    jmp loop   ; start the search loop

loop:
    mov ax, [array+edi*2]       ; move first array element to ax; note a word is 16bits=2bytes
    cmp ax, [number]            ; compare array element with wanted number
    je found                    ; if equal, wanted value is found: jump to "found" address
    inc edi                     ; increment element index
    cmp edi, [length]           ; see if the element was the last element:
    je not_found                ; if so, the wanted number if not found, jump to "not_found"
    jmp loop                    ; repeat the loop

found:
    mov ebx, edi                ; wanted number is found: use "ebx" as an intermediary to store index
    mov [index], bx             ; store index to memory location for index
    jmp end

not_found:
    mov ebx, -1                 ; wanted number is NOT found: use "ebx" as an intermediary to store -1
    mov [index], ebx            ; move -1 to the memory location for index
    jmp end

end:
    mov bx, 0                   ; move interrupt argument to bx
    mov ax, 1                   ; move "1" to ax which means "exit" interrupt
    int 0x80                    ; interrupt: exit
```